# Move an existing NetBeans project to a remote server and place it under version control

Tags: git, netbeans, remote-server

I have a project that I have been working on for about a month. The server we will be using for production has finally been made available. I want to place this project on the server and use Git for version control.

I am trying to follow along with this tutorial, but it is not addressing my situation.  
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

I have intialized a local Git repository in Netbeans (version 7.3 has built in Git support), but what is my next step?

Thanks for any help. First time using Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your next step is to create a bare repository on a remote server in which everyone will be collaborating. You can follow [this tutorial](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) for doing this, or consider a more flexible installation like [Gitolite](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Gitolite).

Is this enough, or do you also want to have a directory on the server with one of the branches checked out?